# Create project in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i have installed ruby and rails using rvm but whenever create a new project it will show the some error:

create

```
/home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /blog (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in `block in invoke!'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `call'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:49:in `invoke!'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:14:in `empty_directory'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:139:in `create_root'
from (eval):1:in `create_root'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Please tell me where i am doing any mistake ... thanks

Comment: `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /blog` << why are you trying to make the app in `/blog` instead of your own home directory? Non-root users usually don't have write access to `/`...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using http://rbenv.org/ instead of rvm its lightweight and simplier to use

before trying to start a new rails project make sure Rails and ruby are properly installed and the basic need of ruby on rails.

I don't on which platform are you working on, but a proper rails environment setup is good to have.

http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/
check this tutorial on proper ruby on rails setup.

after that,  a simple "rails new mynewproject"    should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error. I check its user control

```
ls -ld /NepalRailsProject
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  68 Oct 27 11:02 /NepalRailsProject
```

The other user are not given access to write in file. So change it accessible to file system

```
chmod o+w /NepalRailsProject
```

And check

```
ls -ld /NepalRailsProject
drwxr-xrwx  2 root  wheel  68 Oct 27 11:04 /NepalRailsProject
```

Now, try to create new project, it will create new project.